# Why this regex works with PHP testing but not with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a database with in the column :

1. Sangles D Arrimage à Cliquet
2. sangle
3. Passant pour sangle
4. sangles (seule)
5. Patins Glisseur Téflon angle
6. Charnière d angle

If i run the regex `^(.*\s)*(angles?)(\s.*)*$` in https://regex101.com/, and propose the strings list, i get a match for the line 5 and 6, all is ok. If i run the regex `^(?:.*\s)*(sangles?)(?:\s.*)*$`, i get a match with lines 1, 2, 3, 4, it is okay too.

Now if y put the same regex in a SQL request (on phpmyadmin):

```
SELECT * FROM magasin_article AS mag
WHERE mag_art_libelle REGEXP '^(.*\s)*(angles?)(\s.*)*$'
```

i get the lines 1,2,3,4 !

And with the request :

```
SELECT * FROM magasin_article AS mag
WHERE mag_art_libelle REGEXP '^(.*\s)*(sangles?)(\s.*)*$'
```

I get the result 1,2,4 !

Is there a logical explanation to that ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the MySQL version?

Comment: A better question is: what are your requirements?

Comment: This `(.*\s)*` is meaningless by itself. Matches everything.

Comment: No matter what's going on, unless the default is case insensitive, `sangles?` by itself won't match `Sangle`

Comment: There is the 5.2 version. My goal is to search  more efficiently as with a LIKE.

For instance, in french, "sangle" and "angle" have nothing to do together, so i do not want to have "sangle" result when i search "angle". An other things is for the plural, i want to add the management in order to gives plural and not plural result transparently for the user. "Angle" is naturally a php variable who is replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL (until 8.0?) has a rather lame regexp parser -- few backslash or look-around operators.  MariaDB 10.0 has a better version, and could probably handle what you tried.

Furthermore, MySQL's regexp only handles bytes, not multi-byte characters.  Depending on the `CHARACTER SET`, `é` might be latin1 hex `E9` or utf8 hex `C3 A9`.  The latter would be erroneously treated as 2 characters.

What did you want?  Only lines 5 and 6?  what about `angles` at the start of a line?  What about `Los Angles`?  (Yeah, that is misspelled.)

To get 5 and 6:  `REGEXP ' angle'`

To throw in start-of-line:  `REGEXP '(^| )angle'`

Yes, tacking on `s?` will allow for optional plural.

Also, `[[:<:]]sangle[[:>:]]` will find `sangle` as a "word" -- that is, preceded and followed by space, start/end of string, punctuation, etc.

Comment: Ok; thank's for your comment, it is probably due to that, i have the version 5.5 deploy...

Comment: @Naeco I added a paragraph about how to recognize word boundaries (now that I see that that is really what you are looking for).  I think it works in all versions of MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: Thank you for this add ! I really have never seen such things as "[[:<:]]", and google search do not like this string ^^ Can you give me a keyword to find it in the mySQL manual ? thank's again !

Comment: Search for `mysql regexp`.  Here's the 5.5 page:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html ; it's about half way down the page.  (It is hard to google for punctuation.)

Comment: @Naeco - Even better, google for `mysql word boundary` --  the second result (when I did it) has the syntax quite visible.